# Plot normal distribution when parameters themselves are random variables

Tags: r, plot

I want to plot a normal PDF, where the mean itself is a normally distributed random variable.

X ~ N( mu, 9 ),

where mu ~ N( 50, 4 ).

The following code works well enough:

```
set.seed(121)
mu <- rnorm(100000,mean=50,sd=4)
X <- rnorm(100000,mean=mu,sd=9)
plot(density(mu),lty=2,xlim=c(0,100)) #mu
lines(density(X),lwd=3) #X
```

However, `rnorm` will always generate slight undulations in the curve, even when mapping to a large number observations; as is the case here. (It also takes up unnecessary space.) I prefer to plot normal PDFs with the `curve` command for this reason. Unfortunately, the second line below produces a weird eye-sore:

```
curve(dnorm(x, mean=50, sd=4), 
      from=0, to=100, lty=2, yaxt="n") # mu
curve(dnorm(x, mean=mu, sd=9),
      from=0, to=100, n = length(mu), lwd=3, lty=1, add=TRUE, yaxt="n") # X
```

Does anyone know of a better way to go about this? Is it possible to automatically set "mean=" as a (perfectly distributed) random variable within the `curve` command itself?

Comment: The "undulations" are not from `rnorm(...)`. `density(...)` generates a kernal density estimate, using multiple kernals - what you're seeing is two (or more) kernals almost completely overlapped. If you increase the bandwidth (using `adjust=2` for instance), the undulations go away.

Comment: Ah, good point. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if this helps or not, but your problem is fairly easily solvable mathematically.  The way you have defined your mixture just corresponds to combining the variances of the two distributions:

```
sd1 <- 4; sd2 <- 9
set.seed(121)
mu <- rnorm(100000,mean=50,sd=sd1)
X <- rnorm(100000,mean=mu,sd=sd2)
plot(density(mu),lty=2,xlim=c(0,100)) #mu
lines(density(X),lwd=3) #X
curve(dnorm(x,50,sd=sqrt(sd1^2+sd2^2)),add=TRUE,col=2,lwd=2)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Ben, that's a good point. I am aware that a neat analytical solution presents itself in this particular case. Unfortunately, this was just a MWE and my actual problem involves both parameters (mu and sigma) being random variables... And not necessarily of same distribution family either. Still, your comment is appreciated!

Comment: then I think your best approach will be to just do the simulations and increase the bandwidth/smoothing parameter as @jlhoward suggests (you or they could post that as an answer).